# How to create a RESTful API in php

Tags: php, rest

I'm looking to generate a RESTful API in PHP and based on my experience using them in the past my instinct is to make a PHP script for each function (since they appear at different URLs). However, I then thought that that would be odd because of the levels of hierarchy present in most REST functions I've seen and the fact that none of the REST URLs I've ever seen have any kind of suffix (ie .php). Can someone explain to me the ideal way to setup a RESTful API using PHP so that works the way you might expect a RESTful API to work?

Comment: This isn't a walkthrough site, it requires a solid attempt first. If you have a specific issue, that's what you ask about. This question is simply too broad

Comment: See [`Slim`](http://www.slimframework.com/)

Comment: The question is very specifically what is necessary to achieve the type of URL naming that is used by RESTful interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally if you see domain.com/users/validate that is a clean way of accessing an API using something such as mod_rewrite (.htaccess) for my clients I generally stick with domain.com/?method=SOMETHING,etc.